# mutating table to check text in one column

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a table like below and i want to mutate the table below on the basis column "House" . i have no idea how to start

```
    df <-  data.frame(Region = c("AU","USA","CA","UK","GE","AU","USA","CA","UK"),
                      lock = c(1,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA,1,NA),
                      type= c("sale",NA,NA,"target","target",NA,"sale",NA,"target"),
                      House =c("Tagore house","Gandhi house",NA,"Flexible;Tagore house;Gandhi house","Tagore house",NA,"Flexible;Gandhi house","Gandhi house","Gandhi house"))
```

So the objective is to check column "House" if there is single string like "tagore house" or "Gandhi house" then skip it . then check if there are 2 or more string separated by ";" then add anew row and add the first string like flexible in column house and and another row in column house with tagore house ...so on .

also add the new column of cells having more than one string and add text as head1, head2 ...etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr) # unnest
df %>%
  mutate(House = strsplit(House, ";")) %>%
  unnest(House)
# # A tibble: 12 × 4
#    Region  lock type   House       
#    <chr>  <dbl> <chr>  <chr>       
#  1 AU         1 sale   Tagore house
#  2 USA        1 <NA>   Gandhi house
#  3 CA        NA <NA>   <NA>        
#  4 UK         1 target Flexible    
#  5 UK         1 target Tagore house
#  6 UK         1 target Gandhi house
#  7 GE        NA target Tagore house
#  8 AU         1 <NA>   <NA>        
#  9 USA       NA sale   Flexible    
# 10 USA       NA sale   Gandhi house
# 11 CA         1 <NA>   Gandhi house
# 12 UK        NA target Gandhi house
```

Answer (score 1):

We may use `separate_longer_delim`

```
library(tidyr)
separate_longer_delim(df, House, delim = ";")
```